# What is the different between cryptsetup and truecrypt

Tags: encryption, encrypted-partition, truecrypt

I used truecrypt volume until now, because the space limitation I looked for other solution to encrypt my data. [This](http://jeltsch.org/node/457) is what I found. My question is what is the different between  cryptsetup and truecrypt. Is cryptsetup as safe as truecrypt? What is the best way to encrypt an LVM partition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cryptsetup](http://manpg.es/cryptsetup) is part of the main Ubuntu archive, which means that it's officially support by Ubuntu developers and Canonical.  It's specific to Linux, and provides block device encryption at the kernel level.

[Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is not part of the Ubuntu package archive (due to licensing reasons) and is offered as an additional package that you can add to your Ubuntu system.  Truecrypt does its encryption and decryption in userspace, rather than within the Linux kernel, which actually allows it compatibility clients for Windows and MacOS.